# how to rank a column of numbers while retaining the original position of each number

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I would like to write code for the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test for a Median (a statistical nonparametric test) because I need to do it hundreds of times. I find myself stuck at the code for a crucial step of the test, and was hoping someone would be able to help.

The test involves the following steps:

1. start with a column of values
2. subtract a constant from each value to get a column of differences (with +/- sign retained)
3. now remove all - signs to get only positive values (so absolute differences)
4. rank these absolute differences in order of magnitude (1 to n)
5. add the ranks associated with only the positive differences in step 2.

I am stuck at step 5: how to associate the ranks with the values in step 2?
Here is what I have so far:

```
//Subtract HypMed from values in Column and put abs diffs in array
SetLength(AbsDiffVals, CtrlsList.Count)
for J := 0 to CtrlsList.Count - 1 do 
begin
  Diff := StrToFloat(CtrlsList[J]) - StrToFloat(HypMed);
  DiffVals.Add(FloatToStr(Diff));
  AbsDiff := Abs(Diff);
  AbsDiffVals[J] := AbsDiff;
end;
```

And

```
//sort array AbsDiffVals
for J := 0 to Length(AbsDiffVals)-2 do
begin
  for K := J+1 to Length(AbsDiffVals)-1 do
  begin
    if AbsDiffVals[J] < AbsDiffVals[K] then continue
    else if AbsDiffVals[J] > AbsDiffVals[K] then
    begin
      Temp1 := AbsDiffVals[J];
      Temp2 := AbsDiffVals[K];
      AbsDiffVals[J] := Temp2;
      AbsDiffVals[K] := Temp1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now I need to associate the position of each value in the array (AbsDiffVals), which is the rank of the value, with the corresponding sign in the TStringList DiffVals. This is where I'm stuck, and would like some help.

Comment: You seem, although I admit that I am not sure, to be wanting to re-establish links broken by sorting (the link being the original position in the array). Well, you can't do that. You have to keep the links intact while you sort, either by holding a reference in AbsDiffVals (e.g. by making it a list of record with a field to hold the reference) or to swap the original array positions whenever you swap AbsDiffVals.

Comment: Thank you, @Dsm. I think I may have figured it out. I will post the code after I confirm a couple of things, at which point I would appreciate some feedback on the code.